# Why I don't see any Magento projects in my Magento Cloud account?

Tags: developer-mode, magento2-cloud

I'm a new hired developer for a company that is using Magento CE as their CMS. I'm trying to set up a local development environment and it's telling me that I have to be authorized user on Magento Cloud account. When I log in to our Magento Cloud Account it doesn't show any projects in there, though we have 3 websites on Magento. I got a hold of the original developer and he told me that he developed all websites using the free Magento version.

So I have two questions. Is there any way to connect our websites to the Magento Cloud account? And can I have a development environment is using Magento CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're confusing things. If you're using Magento free version it means that it is Magento Open Source, which should not show in Cloud account. And I'm guessing again, error you're seeing is required authorization when you're trying to do 'composer install' to download magento from repo. You can get this credentials by following steps described here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Comment: Well, we decided to use our hosting company to do the dev site, so I didn't have a chance to try your answer yet. But I will accept your answer for sure. :)